# Why android:onClick attribute causes crash in Android 4.2?

Tags: android, button

I have a button in my application that is supposed to start another activity when clicked. I have added an android:onClick attribute to the button as follows:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_show_toc_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/show_book_content"
        android:onClick="showTOC"

        />
```

And the implementation for showTOC goes:

```
public void showTOC(View view) {
    intent= new Intent(CoverActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,true);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This works fine in Nougat (emulator) and Marshmallow (phone), but crashes on Jelly Bean (emulator and phone) each time the button is clicked, with an error dialog saying "Unfortunately [App Name] has stopped".

Interestingly, using "Button" instead of AppCompatButton or using an onClickListener solves the problem. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Here goes the stacktrace (output from Android Monitor) after the error occurs:

```
06-01 11:55:16.352 3480-3480/mypackage.khateratebook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method showTOC(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btn_show_toc_id'
                                                                              at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showTOC [class android.view.View]
                                                                              at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
                                                                              at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
                                                                              at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Contents of styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
    <style name="BookTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And the only place I have used the BookTheme style is in my third activity i.e. activity_main2.xml in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mypackage.khateratebook.MainActivity2">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp"
        android:theme="@style/BookTheme"
        android:textDirection="rtl"


        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put the stacktrace here

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra stacktrace added.

Comment: it is probably a style issue, put your styles.xml here as well.

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra styles.xml added.

Comment: could you put your activity layout that your AppCompatButton is inside it?